# Changing drive format for OneDrive?

Tags: filesystem, microsoft

I need to use OneDrive on my systems, but ran into a snag on one in particular (I don't know how or why this one machine ended up different).  It's reporting that it can't be used as the file system is case sensitive...

- Is there a procedure to change filesystems without data loss?
- Which filesystem should I be using for best OneDrive compatibility?

Comment: Are you referring to the cloud service OneDrive from Microsoft?  If so, I don't believe you can change the format of a cloud service.

Comment: @fsb I need to change the format on my local machine in order to use OneDrive, not the cloud's format...

Comment: What file system are you currently using on the local machine?

Comment: "Mac OS Extended (Case-sensitive, Journaled)"

Answer (score 3):

This extract from the [Office Support Page from Microsoft](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OneDrive-system-requirements-cc0cb2b8-f446-445c-9b52-d3c2627d681e) lays it all out:

...

• **File systems:** NTFS or HFS+ (case insensitive)

...

See [this page](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/15080/convert-a-partition-from-case-sensitive-to-case-insensitive) from 2011 on StackExchange which recommends a paid app [iPartition](http://coriolis-systems.com/iPartition/) that will apparently change from case sensitive to case insensitive.

Disclaimer: I have no financial or other interest in Coriolis Systems Ltd., developers of iPartition 3.

Comment: While this does not answer the question. Using Disk Utility it's possible to add an APFS volume and tell OneDrive to write there.