# How to make existing Mac OS Extended (Journaled) file system case sensitive?

Tags: disk-utility, partition, disk-format

I've got a fairly large external Thunderbolt RAID-5 filesystem partition. When I get info  (cmd-I) it says "Format: Mac OS Extended (Journaled)".

Further, when I test for case-sensitivity:

```
transom:BlueROV-data dgi$ cat > foo
blah
transom:BlueROV-data dgi$
transom:BlueROV-data dgi$ cat FOO
blah
```

So it looks like this partition is NOT case sensitive. It has got a few terabytes on it, so it would be fairly time-intensive to copy off the data, then reformat.

Is there a way to change the mount parameters for this partition?

Comment: Not sure if these solutions work in the opposite direction, but there was a previous question asked for [case-sensitive to case-insensitive](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/15080/37797).

Comment: Changing mount parameters isn't going to change filesystem structures.